# Number of Tor relays

Tags: tor

I have recently reached https://metrics.torproject.org/relayflags.html and I noticed a spike on 13/01/19. 
According to the graph, almost half of the relays of the network were not online this day. 
Do you have any ideas about how is this possible?

Comment: More than likely the issue was with the monitoring software, not the relays themselves.